# C++ logical error with using dynamic arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

Inside the **insert** function, I use dynamic memory allocation with the arrays **ditems** and **tempItems**.

Where I am using **tempItems** to be an array twice as big as **ditems** and also store all the items from **ditems** temporary; and then deleting and assigning **ditems** equaling **tempItems**

The code complies fine, but when testing it with say enough data requiring **ditems** to store 2000 elements, it appears that the **ditems** array is not getting any bigger.However if I was to set (arrayCap=2001;) in the constructor, then there is no problem.

I am new to using dynamic arrays and looking at other code using dynamic arrays, it doesn't look like I had made any mistakes. I can't use vectors for this task, so I am stuck with dynamic arrays, but I am not sure what is wrong here.

```
template <class T>
class Vector {
    public:
        typedef T* iterator;
        Vector () { 
            arrayCap=1000;
            ditems = new T[arrayCap];
        }

        T& operator[](unsigned int i) {
           return ditems[i];
        }

        iterator begin () {
            used=0;
            return &ditems[used];
        }
        iterator end () { 
            return &ditems[used];
        }
        int size () { return used; }
        void deletes(){

            used--;

        }

        iterator insert (iterator position, const T& item) { 

            if(arrayCap-used<100)
            {
                temp=arrayCap;
                arrayCap=2*arrayCap;

                tempItems=new T[arrayCap];
                for(int i=0; i<temp;i++)
                {
                    tempItems[i]= ditems[i];
                }
                delete [] ditems;
               ditems=tempItems;  
            }

            for(Vector<T>::iterator i=&ditems[arrayCap-1]; i>position; i--)
            {
               *i=*(i-1);
            }
            used++;
            *position= item;
            return position;
        }
    private:
        int arrayCap,temp;
        T *ditems;
        T *tempItems;
        int used;

};
```

Comment: Your `begin()` and `end()` return the same thing. Your range will always appear empty.

Comment: `tempItems` should be a local variable in the `insert` method. There's no reason to make it a class variable. Same is true of the `temp` variable as well.

Comment: Use of the `used` variable is incorrect, it should be set in the constructor not in the `begin` method. The `begin` method should be `return &ditems[0];`

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux not in this case, within other sections of my code not included here, I only call begin() once per creation of an object, so used will increase when I insert more elements into ditems.

Comment: @StackUser when you call your `begin` method you set `used` to zero. In other words calling begin sets the size of your vector to zero. Obviously that's a bug.

Comment: @john **used** doesn't  change the size of my vector, it only keeps track of how many elements are added in it, while **arrayCap** does change size of vector

Comment: @StackUser So what is this doing `int size () { return used; }`? I meant the logical size of your vector, the size a user of your class sees. To put it in your terms calling `begin` changes how many elements have been added to the vector. Again that's a bug.

Comment: @StackUser That doesn't change the fact that `begin() == end()`, which is not how they should behave. For example your type provides `begin()` and `end()` and from the interface appears to support range-based for loops. But it doesn't.

Comment: @john  and Francois Andrieux , Yikes I will have a review of what they should do then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the array to a new position invalidates the iterator `position`, it points to the old array. So `i>position` is undefined behavior.

You should calculate the index before moving the array and set `position` at the index in the new array.

```
template <class T>
class Vector {
    public:
        typedef T* iterator;
        Vector () { 
            arrayCap=1000;
            ditems = new T[arrayCap];
            used = 0;
        }

        T& operator[](unsigned int i) {
           return ditems[i];
        }

        iterator begin () {
            return ditems;
        }
        iterator end () { 
            return &ditems[used];
        }
        int size () { return used; }
        void deletes(){
            used--;
        }

        iterator insert (iterator position, const T& item) { 

            if(arrayCap-used<100)
            {
                auto temp=arrayCap;
                arrayCap*=2;
                auto index = position - ditems;

                auto tempItems=new T[arrayCap];
                for(int i=0; i<temp;i++)
                {
                    tempItems[i]= ditems[i];
                }
                delete [] ditems;
                ditems = tempItems;
                position = ditems + index;
            }

            for(Vector<T>::iterator i=&ditems[arrayCap-1]; i>position; i--)
            {
               *i=*(i-1);
            }
            used++;
            *position = item;
            return position;
        }
    private:
        int arrayCap;
        T *ditems;
        int used;
};
```

Comment: I changed the array before it goes through that loop so shouldn't it point to the new ditems array

Comment: `ditems` will point to the new array, but `position` (the function parameter) does not.

Comment: I think I kind of understand, but then how do I get **position** to point to the new array **ditems**

Comment: `int index = position - ditems;` before moving the array and `position = ditems + index;` afterwards. I added the edited code snippet in the answer.